# I wish two NICs can access Internet on my Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, networking, openvpn

Now I setting OpenVPN server as two instance.

This below is structure of I think

[System structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHafy.png)

Now I can connect to both of OpenVPN #1 and #2

But there's has one problem that OpenVPN #2 can't access to internet after connected vpn.

So I tried find reason and I've almost found

If I try ping as interface "enp0s3" did success, but interface "enp0s8" is not.

My routing rules like this :

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.100.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp0s3
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.2        *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
10.8.1.0        10.8.1.2        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun1
10.8.1.2        *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun1
192.168.100.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp0s8
192.168.100.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp0s3
```

And I insert configuration below to /etc/ufw/before.rules

```
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
# Allow traffic from OpenVPN client to enp0s3
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o enp0s3 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.1.0/24 -o enp0s8 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

I tried few things but I could't do that.

Please help me thank you.

==========================UPDATE==========================

Update post with my `ifconfig`

```
enp0s3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:26:b0:5e  
          inet addr:192.168.100.10  Bcast:192.168.100.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe26:b05e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:18642 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10559 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2674794 (2.6 MB)  TX bytes:1522732 (1.5 MB)

enp0s8    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:17:69:1a  
          inet addr:192.168.100.20  Bcast:192.168.100.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe17:691a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8429 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:354 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:609224 (609.2 KB)  TX bytes:81164 (81.1 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:163 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:163 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:12176 (12.1 KB)  TX bytes:12176 (12.1 KB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.8.0.1  P-t-P:10.8.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:701 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:927 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:123832 (123.8 KB)  TX bytes:616110 (616.1 KB)

tun1      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.8.1.1  P-t-P:10.8.1.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7763 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:475118 (475.1 KB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post the output of "ifconfig"?

In the diagram, you have two seperated networks (192.168.0.0 / 192.168.1.0 / 24) on your nics, but the routing table implies that both nics are configured with an 192.168.100.0/24 address. Are they connected to different physical networks?

So ping responses send over an interface will alway come from enp0s3 - even if they were send to the ip of enp0s3

Comment: Are enp0s3 and enp0s8 connected to the same network?

Comment: Yes "192.168.100.0" is my router network

Comment: Why are you using two different IPs on the same network ? Speed? Performance?

Comment: Because security issue

Comment: I want to allow internal resources(VMs) only admin

Comment: I don't understand: If they are both connected to the same network it doesn't make any difference if they use the same interface with their virtual interface or not.